# Read write mutex on a const reference getter (using Qt)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, mutex

I employ the following scheme in my Model-View-Controller program:

```
class model{

public
const submodelA& getSubModA() const;
const submodelB& getSubModB() const;

private:
submodelA _submod_a;
submodelA _submod_b;

}
```

One thread will write to the submodels using signal-slot connections. Many threads will read from these submodels.

I would therefore like to employ a read-write lock. However, I want to avoid the following:

```
...
_model.getSubModA().getQReadWriteLock().lockForRead();
int foo = _model.getSubModA().getFoo();
_model.getSubModA().getQReadWriteLock().unlock();
...
```

As you can see, this is unnecessarily verbose.

I would like to do just

```
int foo = _model.getSubModA().getFoo();
```

The getters of the submodels should return const references, such as to avoid unnecessary copies.

Is it possible to encapsulate this functionality in the getter somehow?

```
const model::submodelA& getSubModA() const{

_submod_a.getQReadWriteLock().lockForRead();
return _submod_a;

}
```

Obviously, the problem here is that I can't unlock after the return. I was thinking of hacking around this by including a local variable with a reference to the readwrite lock, which would unlock it in its destructor, but I'm worried it could somehow lead to undefined behavior, since it is being returned by reference.

Are there any patterns or practices that solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. Reasons:

1. You want to avoid copies. This means that indeed, you need to return a reference or something similar. In any case, it means that the internally stored object must be made available to the caller.
2. You want to do any locking inside the called function. This means that locking and unlocking must happen inside the function you called. The called function does not have access to the calling code.

In summary, these two requirements conflict. You must hold the mutex while accessing the protected internal data, but at the same time you want to provide access to that data to the caller.

BTW: It's not your question, but you will probably wonder how to solve this. The first thing to notice is that you are optimizing with your requirement to not copy. Alternatively, if that is proven (!) to be a bottleneck, optimize copying instead, e.g. using the handle/body idiom with an immutable body. Further, I wonder what you want to achieve by optimizing the scope of the lock on the mutex. This may as well be a multithreading anti-pattern.